# contact validation failed: name: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "sara smith" at path "name"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

Can anyone help me out for this problem. I don't know whats actually problem with my `req.user.id`. I'm actually new with mongoose.

Here is my `contact.js` file

```
router.post(
  '/',
  [auth, [check('name', 'name is required').not().isEmpty()]],
  async (req, res) => {
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() });
    }

    const { name, email, phone, type } = req.body;

    try {
      const newContact = new Contact({
        name,
        email,
        phone,
        type,
        user: req.user.id,
      });

      console.log("dfdwfwefwe ",req.user.id)

      const contact = await newContact.save();
      res.json(contact);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
      res.status(500).send('Server errors');
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: Is the type of field `name` in `Contact` schema `ObjectId`?

Comment: Yes. It's an ObjectId.

Comment: So currently you are passing `req.body.name` as `sara smith` and its not a valid `ObjectId` and that's why validation error is thrown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably in your contact schema you use

```
name: {
  type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId
}
```

You need to change it to

```
name: {
  type: String
}
```

Because `"sara smith"` is `String`, not `ObjectId`. That's why your validation failed